# missing 1 required positional argument with argument passed through it

Tags: python

I keep getting this error, even though I have passed the value it's asking for through the var. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
class process_raw_snowplow_event_data(luigi.Task):
    dataset_date = luigi.DateParameter(default=date.today() - timedelta(days=1))
    # force_run = luigi.BoolParameter()
    _start = luigi.DateSecondParameter(default=datetime.utcnow())
    file_root = luigi.Parameter()


    @staticmethod
    def download_s3_file(self, s3_filename):

        local_filename = "/Users/xxx/etl/%s" % s3_filename

        s3_file_full_path = re.compile(r"snowplow-enrich-output/enriched/archive/run=" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +r"-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/")

        try:
            s3.download_file(Bucket=os.environ.get('SP_BUCKET'), Key=s3_filename, Filename=local_filename)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("%s - Could not retrieve %s because: %s" % ("download_s3_file()", s3_filename, e))
            raise
```

---

```
class process_sp_data(process_raw_snowplow_event_data):
    def run(self):
        s3_filename = "part_%s.%s.json.gz" % (self.file_root, (self.dataset_date + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        infile_name = self.download_s3_file(s3_filename)
        match_files = self.list_files(os.environ.get('SP_BUCKET'))

        with gzip.open(self.output().path, "wb") as outfile:
            with gzip.open(infile_name, "rb") as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    try:
                        indict = json.loads(line)
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.warn("s -Could not parse line: %s =%s" % (self.__class__.__name__, e, line))
                        continue

                        outdict = indict
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 199, in run
new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 139, in _run_get_new_deps
task_gen = self.task.run()
  File "target.py", line 123, in run
infile_name = self.download_s3_file(s3_filename)
TypeError: download_s3_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 's3_filename'
```

Why isn't this working even though I've passed the argument through it? Thank you for help.

Comment: To my mind, `@staticmethod` is almost always is a code smell, and always a sign of a design problem. Think again why did you think you needed it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling the download_s3_file() method? It looks like you are calling it from the class and not from an instance. Calling it from the class will not supply it with the `self` argument in position 0.

Answer (score 5):

you have specified `@staticmethod`, so `self` isn't the implicit object argument. So when you call:

```
self.download_s3_file(s3_filename)
```

`s3_filename` is set into `self` and ... an argument is missing

either remove `self` or `@staticmethod`

```
@staticmethod
def download_s3_file(s3_filename):
```

or

```
def download_s3_file(self, s3_filename):
```

if you don't use `self` in the method, it is static, so choose first option

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is missing and is set into`self` because you defined your method as a `@staticmethod` so remove the `self` if you want to keep the method as `static`